# React TypeScript in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I use the latest versions of Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code. I've created project using `create-react-app` using TypeScript react scripts version.

I want to make my project being hosted by .NET Core web application, which I've created in Visual Studio. So my react app source code is inside .NET Core app source.

The problem is that my application is working when using Visual Studio Code and development server (the one with live reload). When trying to launch it in Visual Studio (I've added pre-build script to build and copy my react app to wwwroot), it gives me some TypeScript errors. But they don't appear in Visual Studio Code so the problem is for sure with Visual Studio configuration.

Sample error:

```
TS2322  (TS) Type '"GET"' is not assignable to type 'ApiRequestType'

export enum ApiRequestType {
   Get = 'GET',
   Post = 'POST'
}
```

How to fix it? How to make Visual Studio use the same TypeScript version, TypeScript config and TS lint config as Visual Studio Code?
My current TS version is 2.5.3

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

By installing the latest TypeScript SDK from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258

Just why doesn't it update with Visual Studio?